# Elements of NSCollectionView become invisible on resize

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am trying to implement interface which elements are resized on some events. I have a button and a NSCollectionView inside the NSView. The problem is as follows: when resize of the button affects the size of View, sometimes elements of NSCollectionView become invisible. The size of button is changed programatically by enabling a constraint of bigger width.
While some elements are invisible, the NSCollectionView act like if they were visible as usual - I can scroll the collectionView and can see the selectedItem value.
The Layout of NSCollectionView is Content Array (Legacy)

Here are some screenshots:

[Everything is ok from the start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTNQa.png)

[Some elements are invisible after the button became wider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Qe9.png)

Noticeable thing: If **user** resizes the View so that items need to be rearranged, items in NSCollectionView become visible again.

Here is the link to XCode project:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/annv6d7a52h16u6/AACeOUsv2E-ac9q28V3MPjAsa?dl=0

Comment: Are you setting `needsDisplay` and `needsLayout` on `NSCollectionView` to true after resizing the constraint / button?

Comment: @Tritonal I am not setting any of these - only setting the constraint and thats it. Tried to add, but nothing changes.

Comment: Still, it sounds like a layout/drawing problem, if the containers become visible on resize.

Comment: Welcome! You should include images in the question itself and you should also include MRE (Minimal Reproducible Example) in the question too. Why? This question will become useless once images are removed from the imgur service and/or your sample Xcode project is removed from the Dropbox. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: I looked at your sample project and it seems that those views that *were* visible before resize will *become* invisible. They are redrawn only when the whole view will be redrawn. There is a "hack" to fix this, which is to set the prototype item again, but I think there must be a cleaner way to reload the view. You might need to subclass `NSCollectionView` to force redrawing after it has animated & done layout.

Comment: The gray background also has issues. The legacy layout is almost deprecated, is converting to a modern layout an option?

Comment: @Willeke Unfortunately, I can't use other layouts because the project is based on Xamarin.Mac. This technology supports only Content Array (Legacy) layout for NSCollectionView.

Comment: Try switching off "Autoresizes Subviews" of the collection view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Willeke have found a solution:
Switching off "Autoresizes Subviews" of the NSCollectionView fixes the problem.